# How to insert table plugin in ClEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, cleditor

I have

```
<script src="cledtor.js"></script
<script src="cledtortable.js"></script
```

Then in my html i have

```
      $(document).ready(function() {           

                 $("#editor-content").cleditor({
                        width: 708,
                        height: 350,
                        controls:
                            "bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft center alignright justify | size " +
                                "| color removeformat | outdent indent | bullets numbering rule | image link unlink | undo redo | pastetext ",
                        colors:
                            "000000 898989 db0000 005e20 06758c ",

                        sizes:
                            "1,2,3,4,5,6,7",

                        useCSS: false,
                        docType:
                            '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">',
                        docCSSFile: 
                            "",
                        bodyStyle: 
                            "margin:4px; font:10pt Arial,Verdana; cursor:text"
                    });
    });
```

If i add "table" control, it not working. As this code, still no table icon..
I got table.gif image in same place where buttons.gif is

[Official ClEditor page](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)

Answer (score 0):

1: Upload the js file to the same directory as the cleditor js file and include in your js includes (as you've shown)

2: Upload table.gif into the images directory

3: Add "table" into your controls line (without the quotes)

Should appear like any other plugin :-)

Comment: it didn`t work, i found one bug which i don`t remember and now its working